# How to avoid namespace override in windows phone application?

Tags: namespaces, windows-phone-8

I am using ZXing for QrCode scanning. It's throw following error how to solve it?

please Help me. Thanks in advance.

**Error 15  The type 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskStatus' exists in both 'c:\Backup\ZXing.Net.Mobile-master\samples\WindowsPhone\WindowsPhone.Sample\System.Threading.Tasks.WP71.dll' and 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.0\mscorlib.dll'   C:\samples\ContexualContacts\ContexualContacts\MainPage.xaml.cs 53  37  ContexualContacts**

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you are using a WP7 version of ZXing for a WP8 application. Download the binaries for ZXing from [here](http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/103361) and make sure that you use the WP8 binaries. It should resolve the conflict.